# Android Studio previous version is not completely removing and is even not shown in control panel

Tags: android, android-studio

I have completely uninstalled Android Studio 1.5  and installed version 2.3.2. on opening any project the version is still 1.5. on clicking the icon of Android Studio it starts installing version 1.5 again. Initially I upgraded the version 1.5 to 2.3, after uninstalling version 1.5 I am using same upgraded installer for installing version 2.3.

Comment: Which OS are you using? It seems your launcher is still linked to the old version. Anyway, you can just open the executable from your new version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a shortcut somewhere in my C: drive. I reached there and deleted that shortcut. Now it's fine and no issue with new installation.